# SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException: IDX10500: Signature validation failed. No security keys were provided to validate the signature

Tags: openid-connect

I am setting up the OIDC for my application using FusionAuth (https://fusionauth.io). I am using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect` in my .NET core application. After doing the authentication in FusionAuth, it redirect me to `/signin-oidc` on my application (a `GET` request on service provider). Am I missing any configuration on FusionAuth side?

FusionAuth running at: http://localhost:9011

My app: http://localhost:5000

My app gets redirected to FusionAuth for login: http://localhost:9011/oauth2/authorize?client_id=75e33455-f1c5-4e29-8863-53ec28364839&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=636903160481984640.YzMwZWI3ZTEtNzAxOS00MjFhLWIyNGMtYWY5ZGNkODlkY2VjYTNhYjdjMzEtYWMxYy00YThmLWJkYWItYmFiNWY2N2JjMDVk&state=CfDJ8NIq6JMx7khEv5e0kR0710VXenotl3FeHBvCCXUYDrzRVK6Kr7d36hcNMfABQ6pQYZuZQX71QtDFnVH7AczDgHW_8MDNMLFJfy5rF4xIJu2JTPVx3DH2fRp7FOo3ILoAfJfn4b-LnD7Q7zFBx8JO872BME5NXaS6NXiRlUiQQzcb44UNxS8Yn0yVgoQUJLV-iJXCuFlDwtN2z74c8aNhEYJbMiM9GyqiprpqI3p_WocjAyvSAxc7dddkHo7uxD-pBkrldI_v8Z-kVsTwCyBCfCBpKKOIFYvLBfpBcoVjqcSYHfI9GybutW9P4MxeWc2wtykOdBiqcF18ZCN-2yqLSWE&x-client-SKU=ID_NET&x-client-ver=2.1.4.0

After login redirects to: http://localhost:5000/signin-oidc?code=vctVvqZo9zBMHrG9TkY5PZxjW1eqVgTCWnyHY55k3cg&state=CfDJ8NIq6JMx7khEv5e0kR0710VXenotl3FeHBvCCXUYDrzRVK6Kr7d36hcNMfABQ6pQYZuZQX71QtDFnVH7AczDgHW_8MDNMLFJfy5rF4xIJu2JTPVx3DH2fRp7FOo3ILoAfJfn4b-LnD7Q7zFBx8JO872BME5NXaS6NXiRlUiQQzcb44UNxS8Yn0yVgoQUJLV-iJXCuFlDwtN2z74c8aNhEYJbMiM9GyqiprpqI3p_WocjAyvSAxc7dddkHo7uxD-pBkrldI_v8Z-kVsTwCyBCfCBpKKOIFYvLBfpBcoVjqcSYHfI9GybutW9P4MxeWc2wtykOdBiqcF18ZCN-2yqLSWE&userState=Authenticated

I expect that I login to http://localhost:5000 , but I get following error instead.

`SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException: IDX10500: Signature validation failed. No security keys were provided to validate the signature.`

Comment: From a quick search it looks like you might be using the .NET JWT library or their OIDC integration. Can you update the question to help clarify what libraries you are using for the OIDC integration?

Comment: @BrianPontarelli thanks! done with edit.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this library requires a public key in order to validate that the JWT that FusionAuth returns from the `token` endpoint is valid. I'm not a DotNet expert, but from some searching around, the `OpenIdConnectOptions` object is where you configure everything for OIDC. There is a property called `SecurityTokenValidator` that you can add keys to and that might be the best place to start.

Another solution would be to tell the ASP.net Core OIDC library to use the `userinfo` API instead of the JWT stored in the `id_token`. This will cause DotNet to call back to FusionAuth's `userinfo` API and then FusionAuth will handle all of the validation for you and respond with the OIDC claims from the JWT. The property `GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint` on the `OpenIdConnectOptions` object looks like it enables this. I couldn't figure out how to tell DotNet the URL of the `userinfo` API though. Here's an example of that configuration:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)  
{

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseIdentity();

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {
            ClientId = Configuration["ClientId"],
            ClientSecret = Configuration["ClientSecret"],
            Authority = Configuration["Authority"],
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
            GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true
        });

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

I got that code from this blog post:

https://andrewlock.net/an-introduction-to-openid-connect-in-asp-net-core/

You might need to do some additional searching and reading up on the DotNet OIDC integration to get this all working. There isn't a lot of information out there, but a few people have written blogs on this topic that might help.

Answer (score -1):

Finally got the solution

```cs
services.AddOpenIdConnect(options => {
    ...
    options.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("lOB8KJK2gKn2c6ZFJIKpVqLM-gHa6WmFvSJfHWUKscs"));
    ...
}
```

I missed adding the key from FusionAuth to my application, which is used to verify the token.

Comment: what is this key "lOB8KJK2gKn2c6ZFJIKpVqLM-gHa6WmFvSJfHWUKscs"? i mean where to get this?? i am using my company provided pingfederate. All i got from security team was clientid and clientsecret